# Why does using stoi here give me errors?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read 2nd and third lines of input, where the first number on the two lines is the length of the array ( the no. of digits on the line excluding spaces and the first number ). I want to store the length of the arrays in a separate array and print out the rest of the numbers on those lines to STDOUT. I currently have the following code but I'm getting errors related to the stoi function..

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int numarr;
    int numqueries;
    string line;
    char chars;

    scanf("%d %d",&numarr,&numqueries);
    vector<string> lengths = vector<string>(numarr);
    vector<int> arrays = vector<int>(numarr);
    vector<int> queries = vector<int>(numqueries); 
    int lq = 0;
    while(getline(cin,line) && lq <= numarr){
        stringstream iss(line);
        string wd;
        string dd;
        int cnt = 1;
        while(cnt == 1 || (iss >> wd && cnt < stoi(lengths[cnt-1]))){
            if(cnt == 1){
                lengths[cnt-1] = wd;
                cout << "first";
                cnt++;
            }else{
            cout << wd;
            cnt++;  
            }   
        }
        lq += 1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

error output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'

  what():  stoi

Reading symbols from Solution...done.

[New LWP 499362]

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Core was generated by `./Solution'.

Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51

To enable execution of this file add

    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py

line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

To completely disable this security protection add

    set auto-load safe-path /

line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

For more information about this security protection see the

"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:

    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

example input:

```
2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
1 3
```

Comment: `lengths[cnt-1]` is read for `stoi` before it is written. (`lengths[cnt-1]` won't be written unless `cnt==1`)

Comment: Can you provide sample input? @MikeCAT good point, but `cnt` is 1.

Comment: I've set cnt to 1 just before the loop starts so it should be written the first time (?)

Comment: You really shouldn't mix the old C input/output functions with C++ stream input/output.

Comment: Also think about what happens with the `Enter` key (and the newline it adds) after the initial input you read with the `scanf` function.

Comment: Think about the loop condition... When do you write to `lengths[0]` and when do you pass `lengths[0]` to `stoi`?

Comment: @gsamaras For example, input `2 1 1 1` invoked the `stoi` error.

Comment: Use `gdb` to step through your code from the beginning and observe the simple fact that `lengths[0]` is never initialized before it gets passed as a parameter to `stoi()`. Your question shows that you know it exists and you know how to start it. So, use `gdb` to run your program, one line at a time, and you can easily figure out the bug yourself. This is exactly what `gdb` is for. It's much faster for you to simply step through your program, one line at a time, yourself, and figure it out.

Comment: note: using `getline` after `scanf` in this style will cause a trouble because `scanf` won't consume the newline character. You can avoid this trouble, for example, by reading the first line also via `getline` and parse it via `sscanf`.